# Text box with same elements in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a text box to enter some card details. I have two cases

1) Entering in this text box before login to the account
2) Entering in this text box after login to the account

The elements of this text box after login into the account replicates i.e, I get two `id="cn"` in the page source hence my driver is not able to find the element and hence cannot enter to the text box.

Using the absolute `xpath` is not an option since it is changing dynamically.

Below is the `html`:

Before login I only get the below:

`html/body/div/div/div[12]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/form/ul/li[1]/p/input[1]`

```
        <ul class="grid">
            <li class="mb20 card-wrapper">
                <label class="mb10" for="cardNumber">ENTER CREDIT CARD NUMBER</label>
                <p class="cd">

                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="" class="ccCardNumber  text-input large-input c cardInput type-tel" id="cn" size="16" maxlength="19" style="width: 278px" data-type="cc" 
                    value=""> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="cardNumber" value="" class="required">
                </p>
```

After login I get as below:

`html/body/div/div/div[12]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/form/ul/li[1]/p/input[1]`

```
        <ul class="grid">
            <li class="mb20 card-wrapper">
                <label class="mb10" for="cardNumber">ENTER CREDIT CARD NUMBER</label>
                <p class="cd">

                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="" class="ccCardNumber  text-input large-input c cardInput type-tel" id="cn" size="16" maxlength="19" style="width: 278px" data-type="cc" 
                    value=""> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="cardNumber" value="" class="required">
                </p>
```

and

```
        <input type="hidden" name="addMoney" value="1" />
        <ul class="grid">
            <li class="mb20 card-wrapper">
                <label class="mb10" for="cardNumber">ENTER CREDIT CARD NUMBER</label>
                <p class="cd">

                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="" class="ccCardNumber  text-input large-input c cardInput type-tel" id="cn" size="16" maxlength="19" style="width: 278px" data-type="cc" 
                    value=""> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="cardNumber" value="" class="required">
                </p>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: You can use index of exact element. Also this seem to be a bug, so you'd better to report your dev team before making any changes to your test framework...

Comment: If 2 are present in HTML and only one is seen in the UI, the duplicate HTML must be hidden using a parent tag (Eg: div). Look for this and write xpath accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML structurers seems the same for every input, so you are able to locate all inputs in the same way with xpath, you can try this one:

```
//li[descendant::*[contains(text(),'ENTER CREDIT CARD NUMBER')]]//input[@type='text']
```

If only one text box is displayed in the Browser, but you can find more than one in the HTML then you can try to locate only visible elements:

```
  String xpath = "//li[descendant::*[contains(text(),'ENTER CREDIT CARD NUMBER')]]//input[@type='text']";
  WebElement visibleInput = findVisibleElement(xpath);
```

The `findVisibleElement ()` method body is bellow:

```
public WebElement findVisibleElement(final String xpath) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver input) {
            Iterator<WebElement> iterator = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                WebElement element = iterator.next();
                try {
                    if (element.isDisplayed())
                    return element;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Note that in this case I used the label text as a reference into xpath string, but you can use any other cssSelector instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to find the element using the xpath in Firebug however in the real code, I am not able to find it. After using the second option you provided, I am getting an exception as below:                                  Timed out after 500 seconds waiting for visibility of all elements located by By.xpath: //li[descendant::*[contains(text(),'ENTER CREDIT CARD NUMBER')]]//input[@type='text']
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'

Comment: Take care with ExpectedConditions you selected. It looks like you selected `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(xpath)));` instead of `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));`

Comment: I did exactly what you said and got the below error now: Timed out after 80 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //li[descendant::*[contains(text(),'ENTER CREDIT CARD NUMBER')]]//input[@type='text']

Comment: I created a new function wich will find both inputs and will return the visible one. I really hope this works. I edited my previous answer to provide a new function.

Comment: I was able to find the element with the help of your code but how can I use the returned element to sendkeys the text data ?

Comment: Using the `sendKeys ()` method like:  `visibleInput.sendKeys (yourTextHere);`